# What is the best practice to get events from a users google calendar?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I want to read events from a users google calendar and use the title of the events for future purposes in an android app.

So far I've read the documentation about the google-calendar-api and the calendar-provider and so on but couldn't get any of the "getting started" guides to run. I also couldn't find any useful example on how to implement the api.

I am aware of the process (User needs to authenticate himself with his google account and with that information the desired content can be accessed) but as I said, I am unaware of how to implement this inside an android app.

If anyone has useful code, an example or any advice, I'd really appreciate it since this simple topic was driving me crazy.

Comment: This is too broad, you need to be more precise and focus on a specific code. Also, remember that SO is not a free coding service. You should take the guide code that suits you best, share it in the question itself with all the relavant details: the error code if there is any, or describe how the behaviour is unexpected. For the process, identifying with your google account will only work if you are in a browser (if browser is embedded in the app, you need to log in there). If not in a browser, you need to log in manually to the API, with your credentials (hide them in the code you share here)

Comment: @Kaddath I understand that this question is quite broad but I don't want anyone to give detailed explanation. Maybe somebody faced the same problems but found a solution that suits them or anybody has a github reference. 
And no, a browser is not necessary. You can of course authenticate yourself with your google account inside an app. And you don't have to hide any credentials inside the code, you can use smartlock to store them and to automatically log in the user with his credentials when launching the app. And this was not the problem that I was facing.

Comment: It's not that it's too broad that it cannot be answered at all, it's too broad for this site rules, even off-topic if what you want is tutorials. And because there is nothing more specific than "cannot get it to work", very unlikely that the post can be useful for others. About hiding your credentials, it was if you share your code here, so that other users don't see them.

Comment: @Kaddath I often had the experience on stack overflow where people shared there experience with facing the same problem even without given a specific context. And I often found the provided links or projects as an answer pretty useful. If this won't be answered here it's fine for me but if anyobdy has a recommendation for me, the question payed itself off

Answer (score 0):

Using Content provider you can access Calendar Events, Content resolver query() method is used to get content provider data. You need to pass list of columns that need to be retrieved.

you can take refrence from android calendar docs check below link https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar

```
  // add below permission in your manifest file and ask these permission at run time also
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>


  public void getDataFromEventsTable() {
    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();

    //if you want access calendar details use below uri
   // Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] calmProjection ={CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE,
                    CalendarContract.Calendars.ALLOWED_REMINDERS};

    //if your want access event related info use below uri
    Uri uri=CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] eventmProjection =
            {CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
                    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.ORGANIZER,
                    CalendarContract.Events._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DURATION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_DATA1,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DIRTY,
                    CalendarContract.Events.UID_2445,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DELETED,
                    CalendarContract.Events.LAST_DATE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_DATA2,
                    CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY,
                    CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.STATUS,
                    CalendarContract.Events.RDATE
            };

    String selection = "((" + CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND ("
            + CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
            + CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
  // pass here details of account, which account linked with your google calendar 
 String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"xyz@gmail.com", "com.google",
            "xyz@gmail.com"};

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},12);
    }
    cur = cr.query(uri, eventmProjection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
       if(cur.getCount()>0){
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String eventTitle = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
            String eventId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events._ID));
            String startDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART));
            String endDate = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND));
            Log.d("Events", "->" + eventTitle + "->" + eventId + "->" + startDate + "->" + endDate);
        }
        }
}
```